# How to add columns dynamically using jquery according to the total count of records

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated

I want to render html table with two rows and one column. If the total count of records from HttpHandler is greater than 2 ,the extra record will be inserted behind the first column. Thank you in advance.

Html table will be rendered:

```
RealName    RealName    RealName
Name1       Name3       Name5
Name2       Name4
```

Here is my js snippet:

```
function fillSuccess(rsp) {
 var str = "<table width='100%'><tr><td>RealName</td></tr>";
 for (var i = 0; i < rsp.length; i++) {
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
       // how to implement here 
     }
     else { 
     str += "<tr ><td>" + rsp[i].RealName + "</td>";
     }
 }
 str += "</tr></table>";
 $('#divTitle').append(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with an odd or even count:

```
var rsp     = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

var count   = rsp.length;
var cols    = Math.ceil(count / 2);

var value    = '<table>';
value       += '<tr>';

for (var i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    value       += '<th>RealName</th>';
}
value       += '</tr>';

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    value       += '<tr>';

    for (var j = 0 + i; j < count; j = j+2) {
        value       += '<td>' + j + '--' + rsp[j] + '</td>';
    }
    value       += '</tr>';
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmHSY/

Comment: ,thanks ,When I run your code in http://jsfiddle.net/,The table html is not well-formed and 'RealName' does not display on the other column header.

Comment: @KevinAuds Ah sorry, I had a different output totally. Haha. So I've updated the code and now it should give you the expected result. :)